# Everyauth example fails with "At step, fetchOAuthUser, you are trying to access the parameters: accessToken"

Tags: node.js, everyauth

I have a fresh install of everyauth and running the example code produces the error:
*At step, fetchOAuthUser, you are trying to access the parameters: accessToken. However, only the following parameters have been promised from prior steps thus far: req, res, next.* 
I have tried the npm install as well as a git clone with the same result.  I have resolved the known error with a missing } in conf.js.

To be clear, I am executing:

```
cd example/
node server.js
```

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.  It turns out that Express was already installed and if that is the case then you must use the  "npm install git://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth.git#express3" command to install everyauth.